# Docker compose run throws error on entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, caddy

Running the following cmd:

`docker-compose up -d`

Throws the following error:

```
ERROR: for ubuntu_caddy_1  Cannot start service caddy: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"./caddy\": stat ./caddy: no such file or directory"
```

Here is `docker-compose.yml` file

```
services:
  caddy:
    image: abiosoft/caddy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "2015:2015"
    volumes:
      - "./caddy-data:/root/.caddy"
      - "./config:/etc/caddy"
      - "./config/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile"
    entrypoint:
      - ./caddy
      - "-conf"
      - /etc/Caddyfile
      - "-agree"
      - "-log=stdout"
      - "-port=443"
    restart: "on-failure: 10"
    user: root
version: "2"
```

Any idea on what I would be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the abiosoft/caddy Dockerfile, the standard entrypoint is `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/parent", "caddy"]` ([link here](https://hub.docker.com/r/abiosoft/caddy/dockerfile)).

So I think that you must change `./caddy` in your entrypoint by `/bin/parent caddy`.

I also think that you don't have to overwrite the default entrypoint, you just have to specify your args to caddy by overwriting the default command (which is `CMD ["--conf", "/etc/Caddyfile", "--log", "stdout", "--agree=$ACME_AGREE"]`).

So you end up with `command: -conf /etc/Caddyfile -agree -log=stdout -port=443`.

Comment: No you don't need it, because you don't have to overwrite the default one.